# Creating random strings and storing in array

Tags: c#, arrays

So I have a way to create random strings which I found on this site, but I have no idea how to store each string in an array.

```
 var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789";
            var random = new Random();
                for (int i=0; i < 50; i++)
             {
                var result = new string(
    Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 4)
              .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
              .ToArray());                 
            }
```

Perhaps it has something to do with `.ToArray());` but I have no idea where that comes from. What even is `Enumerable.Repeat`?

Comment: "What even is `Enumerable.Repeat`" - Sorry but [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Enumerable.Repeat) is your [friend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348899%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: @Wilbo007 Again, [Google](https://www.google.ae/search?noj=1&biw=1920&bih=969&q=enumerable.select&oq=enumerable.se&gs_l=serp.3.0.0l5j0i30l5.1143775.1145978.0.1146858.13.10.0.3.3.1.316.1477.0j4j2j1.7.0.msedr...0...1c.1.60.serp..4.9.1170.wsN7olKF4ds) is your [friend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Why no use `String s = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`?

Answer (score 1):

To create your array of 50 strings of 4 random characters each:

```
var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789";
var random = new Random();

var stringArray =
    Enumerable.Repeat(0, 50)
    .Select(i => new string(
        Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 4)
        .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
        .ToArray()))
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything with the `result` - it simply goes out of scope in your loop. It is a single string of 4 random characters.

`Enumerable.Repeat` creates an collection of repeated string references to of 'chars' (4 copies), which is then used by the `Random` to fetch a single character from each string.

You can project an array of 50 random strings of 4 characters each without a for loop, using `Enumerable.Range`. Also, the algorithm doesn't need to create 4 references to string - we can reference the original string.

```
var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789";
var random = new Random();
var result = Enumerable.Range(0,50)
    .Select(i => new string(
        Enumerable.Range(0, 4)
            .Select(x => chars[random.Next(chars.Length)])
            .ToArray()));
```